# Angular 4: build --prod: keyboard events do not fire

Tags: angular, events, keyboard

Once I have built my Angular app for production:

```
ng build --prod
```

None of my keyboard events fire:

**chat-window.component.html:**

```
<input type="text" class="chat-input" placeholder="Write your message here..." (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)" (keydown)="onKeydown($event)" (focus)="onFocus($event)" [(ngModel)]="draftMessage.text" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn-chat" (click)="onEnter($event)">Send</button>
</span>
```

The HTML snippet above is not contained within:

```
<form></form>
```

**chat-window.component.ts:**

```
onEnter(event: any): void {
    console.log('CHAT-WINDOW: keydown.enter: event',event);
    this.sendMessage();
    event.preventDefault();
}

onKeydown(event: any): void {
    console.log('CHAT-WINDOW: keydown: event',event);
}
```

When pressing the 'enter' button inside the input field, nothing happens. No console message, and the message is not sent. I added the '(keydown)' event handler just to see if any 'keydown' events get fired. And nothing.

Orginally this issue arose, using only '(keydown.enter)'. I only added the '(keydown)' to see if any keydown events would register. I have also tried removing the 'event.preventDefault();' and still nothing fires.

However, the click event on the button works, so mouse events seem to be OK.

In development mode [localhost:4200] everything works as expected. In other words, the relevant console messages are displayed and the message gets sent.

Can anyone tell me why my keyboard events do not register when I am using the compiled version of my app?

**Environment:**

```
"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",

"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
```

**Tested on:**

```
Firefox [latest version]
Chrome [latest version]
Edge [latest version]
```

Comment: Does it work if you only bind to a single event, either `keydown` or `keydown.enter` ? I suspect a collision

Comment: No. I started off with just keydown.enter & it did NOT register, so I tried testing any keydown event and still nothing.

Comment: However, the click event on the button works, thankfully...